# jquery input value change on mouseover

Tags: jquery, forms, input, jquery-validate, validation

I want to implement jquery/js in my forms and I want to make input values dynamic.
Basically the idea is that once clicked the value of the field disappears/blurs and
jquery expects the user to insert a value, if a value is set and it is not the same
as the default value then it's okay. But if the value written by the user is the same
then don't accept and throw an error, else if the value "entered" by the user is empty
display the default value again. Im sure it makes sense as I think i've seen this functionality implementet in a lot of sites. But I'm now a jquery guy so I dont know
how to do it. I can do the same in php but page refreshing is something I want to avoid.
So assuming we have:

```
<input type="text" value="City" />
```

Thank you alot,
Borni.

Comment: `$('input').mouseover(function(){ $(this).trigger('focus'); })`

Comment: how to do it with jquery/javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this [here?](http://jsfiddle.net/justeric/gbjvU/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[class="foo"]').attr('value', $(this).attr('placeholder')).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val('placeholder')) {
            $(this).attr('value', '');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('placeholder'))
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Updated code and fiddle with suggestions provided by Christopher Ramírez

Comment: Thanks this is precisely what I wanted. THANKS THANKS.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)

Comment: Thank you all clear now. I just visited jsfidle and totally understood your jquery code at the moment I saw the html.

Comment: This is not a good solution because it use a global variable to store the placeholder value. Try to use a attribute stored on each input element instead a variable. The ideal attribute is actually the `placeholder`.

Comment: `placholder` doesn't work on all browsers because it is an HTML5 attribute, I simply suggested an alternate method that I always use. As a side note I was the one that upvoted your answer before I submited my own:)

Comment: Thanks for voting :) Browsers which don't support `placeholder` attribute simply will ignore it. Your code is good, but the flaw is that it use variables. Just changing: `$(this).attr('value', default_0)` for `$(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('placeholder'))` will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called "placeholder". Them are implemented in modern browser like Webkit and Mozilla. I'm not sure if newer versions of IE implement them.

To use them, declare a new attribute in your `input` elements called `placeholder`. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Type your full name" />
```

As a backup, when `placeholder` attribute is not supported by the browser, [this arclicle](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html) may help get where you want

UPDATE: [This is a plugin](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/) I've just found. Seems easy to use.